# Django ManyToMany relationship details of details

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views, manytomanyfield

I have read well the Django documentation on the ManyToMany filed. Especially the one [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/) . I am quite clear of the things that can be done with it. For instance if I have a Category model and a Startup model where a category can have many startups and a startup can belong to many categories, then ManyToMany relationship is useful here. I am able to list all categories on my template, each category is clickable and leads to a list of all startups on another template belonging to this category. 
Now, having had this, I want to go a bit further. Having gone to the detail page of a specific category, which is a list of startups belonging to it, I want each item in this details page to also lead to another details page where I can display more information about a specific startup.

My main problem is now how I can implement it. I have gone through the many questions asked relating to ManyToMany field and its queries, especially [here](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=How+to+access+ManyToMany+relationship+in+django+template)  but they seem to all be taking about how to access the related objects to a category for example in a details page and it ends there. I want to go from the details page to another details page.

```
from django.db import models
```

my Category model:

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.Charfield(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def get_startups(self):
        return Startup.objects.filter(category=self)
```

My Startup models:

```
class Startup(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    founder_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    short_description = models.CharField(max_length=225)
    concept = models.TextField(help_text='how does this startup operate?')
    category = models.ManyToManyField(Category)
    website = models.URLField(max_length=225)
    logo = models.ImageField()


    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    @property
    def logo_url(self):
        if self.logo and hasattr(self.logo, 'url'):
            return self.logo.url
```

In my views.py file:

```
class CategoryView(ListView):
    template_name = 'myapp/startup-category.html'
    context_object_name = 'category_list'

    def get_queryset(self): 
        return Category.objects.all()


class DetailView(DetailView):
    model=Category
    template_name = 'myapp/startup-list.html'
```

In my templates/myapp/startup-category:

```
{% if category_list %}
<ul>
    {% for category in category-list %}
        <li><a href="{% url 'detail' category.pk %}">{{category.name}}</a></li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
{% endif %}
```

In templates/myapp/startup-list.html :

```
{% for startup in category.get_startups %}
    <tr>
        {% if startup.logo %}
        <td><img src="{{ startup.logo_url|default_if_none:'#' }}" style="height: 50px; width: 50px;"></td>
        {% endif %}
        <td>{{startup.name}}</td>
        <td> {{startup.short_description}}</td>
        <td>
            <button type="button" ><a href="">View startup</a>
            </button></td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

In myapp.urls:

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views as core_views

path('startup_categories/', core_views.CategoryView.as_view(), name='startups'),
path('startup_categories/<int:pk>/', core_views.DetailView.as_view(), name='detail'),
```

This works fine. I get a list of categories; when I click on a category, it takes me to a details page where I get list of startups related to this category in a tabular form. On each startup element, there is a button that seeks to view the details of the startup. 
How do I do implement the view of the startup details?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

define a url something like:

```
 path('/startup/<int:startup_id>', views.view_startup, name='view-startup'),
```

In forms.py : (if you dont have forms.py, create it in the same app)

```
 from .models import Startup
 from django.forms import ModelForm

 class StartupForm(ModelForm):
      class Meta:
           model = Startup
           fields = ['name', 'founder_name'] #Put name of all the fields that you want to display in template here
```

In views.py

```
 from .forms import StartupForm
 def view_startup(request, startup_id):
     startup = get_object_or_404(Startup, pk=startup_id)
     startup_details_form = StartupForm(instance = startup)

     return render(request, "startup_details.html", {"form":startup_details_form})
```

In startup_details.html

```
  {% for field in form %}
       {{ field.label_tag }} : {{ field.value }}
  {% endfor %}
```

Now in your startuplist.html you can simply put

```
  <button type="button" ><a href="{% url 'view-startup' startup.id %}">View startup</a>
```

This is just to give you a basic idea. It probably is not a good practice to use IDs in urls. You can make another slug field in your startup model that will contain the url and then you can modify the relevant files to actually use the slug instead of ID

Comment: Why do you need the if? Arent you always sending the form?

Comment: That works! The only thing is that for the logos, it displays the names instead of the images. To tackle that, I stopped looping through the fields and rather did:  `{% if form %}`   `<p>Name: {{form.name.value}}</p`  `<p>Founder: {{form.founder_name.value}}</p>` `<img src='http://localhost:8000/{{form.logo.value}}'>`  `{% endif %}`  I will look at how to fix the hard-coded image url. I defined that in my Startup model but it appears I cannot access that through the forms. Or maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: @codeDude Yes, in this case, it is not necessary. I'm fond of using `if` so to be able to handle errors. I don't need that here though.

Comment: @JohnBagiliko For images if you use {{ form.logo.value.url }}, you will get complete path.

PS: If it worked properly, could you accept the answer?